# whereJsonContains not returning anyting

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following blocks of code

```
try {

            $data = Checklist::where('setupStatus', true)->whereJsonContains('workspaceRegions', $regionID)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

            return response()->json([
                'data' => $data
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th;
        }
```

This works as expected and returns the correct checklists.

So then I did the same in the next block, but this time I have to iterate through and array to get the id values to search for. This always return an empty array though

```
$company = Auth::user()->company;
        try {
            $hodIDs = CompanyRoles::where('hod', true)->get();

            $hods = [];
            foreach ($hodIDs as $option) {
                $id = strval($option->id);
                $hods = User::where('companyID', $company->id)->whereJsonContains('companyRoles', $id)->with('employee')->get();
            }

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'success',
                'hods' => $hods
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th;
        }
```

The 'companyRoles' column is an array that contains something like ["1","2"]

How can I return each user with and hodID within the companyRoles column array?

The following gives me what I want, but this feels a bit like a hack.

```
$hods = [];
            foreach ($hodIDs as $option) {
                $id = strval($option->id);
                $user = User::where('companyID', $company->id)->whereJsonContains('companyRoles', $id)->with('employee')->first();

                if ($user) {
                    array_push($hods, $user);
                }
            }
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Can you show me the SQL returned by your query?

Comment: hey, I get this

hods: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, role: "Senior HSE Manager", hod: 1}
1: {id: 3, role: "Chief Executive Officer", hod: 1}
2: {id: 28, role: "Project Manager", hod: 1}
3: {id: 31, role: "HOD", hod: 1}

Comment: made an edit to the question to add a solution that I have come up with, but it I am sure it can be done better